# How to assign an array's key value pairs to object's attribute value pairs in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, assign

I wanted to know How to assign an array's key value pairs to an object's attribute value pairs in PHP. This is what I'm trying. I'm using a constructor to set all the attributes by sending all the values frm array through parameter while creating the object. But I believe there should be a more concise and efficient way to do this. if anyone know please share.

```
function display_stock($connection)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `stock` ";
 $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 $stock = array();
 for ($i = 0;$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $i++)
 {
    $stock[$i] = new stock( $row);
 }
return $stock;
}
```

This is the code of constructor

```
public function __construct($l_code, $date, $all_lengths_size, $overall_cost)
{
    $this->l_code=$l_code;
    $this->date=$date;
    $this->all_lengths_size=$all_lengths_size;
    $this->overall_cost=$overall_cost;
}
```

Note that i have to return an array of objects so pass only $row is not feasible here.

Comment: not really, unless you want to pass in the array itself, `new sale($row)` and have the constructor pull out whatever bits its needs.

Comment: May be that's a better approach, Because this one seems lengthy !

Comment: I agree with @MarcB's approach. What if your rows change also? You don't want to have to change code in this long object declaration as well as in its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a constructor that set the properties accordingly, like this:

```
public function __construct($row){
 foreach ($row as $prop=>$value){
  $this->$prop=$value;
 }
}
```

or you can set only the properties of your interest like this

```
public function __construct($row){
  $propertiesilike=array("customer_name", "p_type");
 foreach ($propertiesilike as $prop=>$val){
  if(isset($row[$prop])){
   $this->$prop=$row[$prop];
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: 1st one is cool. But in second one where do u assume $value is coming from ? its undefined !
I believe you wanted to write this
    $this->$prop=$row[$prop];

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should be $this->$prop=$row[$prop] - edited

Answer (score 2):

Another option, assuming that the query is returning the columns that should populate the object, you can use `mysqli_fetch_object()`:

```
while($sale[] = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'sale')) {}
```

This populates the properties before calling `__construct()`.  There is a third parameter to pass parameters to the constructor.

Comment: Minor improvement: `sale::class` is better instead of `'sale'`.